# hasClass always returns false even when toggling it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="add-new">
    <input type="submit" class="hidden" id="add-new" value="Add new">
<form>
```

and a js with this code on

```
$("#add-new").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() === "Add"){
        $(this).val("Cancel");            
    }else{
        $(this).val("Add");
    }
    console.log($(".add-new").hasClass('hidden')); // this is always false why??           

    $(".add-new").val("").toggleClass('hidden');
    if ($(".add-new").hasClass('hidden') === false) {
        $(".add-new").focus();            
    }
});
```

Although I always enter the if I never get focus on the input box. Why is it always false since I toggle it? From chorme's command line works great but the focus still won't work. Please since I've been over 9 hours in front of my pc do you see anything wrong with my javascript code?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/4wZGd/

Comment: I tried it as well and get alternating true/false in my console.

Comment: Is the page reloading? You have `event.preventDefault()`, so it shouldn't, but worth a check.

Comment: Is there any change that there is another part of your code you are not sharing with us? two elements with same id, un-closed tag etc?
*works fine here as well, using firefox 28.xx*

Comment: Then probably it must be me...I will double check...

Comment: does not works for you @adeneo 's fiddle too?

Comment: It worked. Just copied pasted the selector and worked. Guess after But I am infront of my pc for aprox 11 hours so...Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Which input do you want to find?
At this point `console.log($(".add-new").hasClass('hidden'));` input with class `.add-new` doesn't have class `.hidden`

```
$(".add-new").val("").toggleClass('hidden'); // Now it has
if ($(".add-new").hasClass('hidden') === false) { // And it will be always false because now it has .hidden
    $(".add-new").focus();            
}
```