# hasClass() always returns false (jquery) even when toggling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It prints out `false` for every single log to the console. Toggling works fine when clicking the nav link and cancel button. I've look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994767/hasclass-always-returns-false-even-when-toggling-it) and tried all the suggestions but still had the same problem.

```js
// add new photo toggle
$('#click_new_photo a').click(function() {
  console.log($(".content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
  $(".content").find(".new-photo").toggleClass('show-new-photo');
  console.log($(".content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
});

$("#cancel_add_new_photo").click(function() {
  console.log($(".content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
  $(".new-photo").toggleClass("show-new-photo");
  console.log($(".content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
});
```

```css
.new-photo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #34609d;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #d6d6d6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show-new-photo {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="click_new_photo"><a href="#">New Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="new-photo">
      <button id="cancel_add_new_photo">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: in your demo there is no class `'show-new-photo'` in content

Comment: Also the selector "content" is quite distinctly different from ".content"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the hasClass method don´t work with child nodes.

You can use something like that

```
return $(".content").find('.show-new-photo').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe

```
$(".content").find(".new-photo").toggleClass('show-new-photo');
```

only toggles the 'show-new-photo' class on the '.new-photo' element, not the ".content" element.

Unless I'm missing something

```
console.log($("content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
```

will out put the same thing whether it's before or after

```
$(".content").find(".new-photo").toggleClass('show-new-photo');
```

because that line of code does not change whether or not $(".content") has the class "show-new-photo" or not.

Also it should be $(".content"), not $("content").

Comment: Is there anyway that I could test whether `show-new-photo` is or is not on the screen if this way is flawed?

Comment: @stumped not totally sure what you mean. Do you want to test whether any element in your DOM has the class `show-new-photo`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log($(".content").hasClass('show-new-photo'));
```

I believe this should work by adding the class "." in your selector

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It still shows up all false though even with the changes

Comment: I generally try to use ids for something like this.  I have tested on my end and i believe it should be working.  You could try with an id attribute and switch your code to this : console.log($("#contentID").hasClass('show-new-photo'));